# Simple comma in session value ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the next code and works fine:

```
var nombreregion = '<%= Session["regionNombre"]%>';
```

But if the value has a simple comma (') ocurrs the next error:

```
var nombreregion = 'LIBERTADOR GRAL B.O'HIGGINS';
```

The value is truncated...

How can i prevent this error?

Comment: Try var nombreregion = 'LIBERTADOR GRAL B.O\'HIGGINS\';

Comment: As commented in one of suggested answers below, the solution lies in encoding the single quote to avoid it generating syntax error. Alternatively consider re-writing the code to avoid using <% syntax altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Session["regionNombre"]` runs at server-side. So, you want to use [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method to sanitize the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nombreregion = 
        '<%= ((string)(Session["regionNombre"] ?? "")).Replace("'", "\\'") %>';
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks win, your solution was very helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by escaping the single quote (').  Like so:

```
'LIBERTADOR GRAL B.O\'HIGGINS'
```

For more information on escaping quotes you can view the "Special Characters" section of this page:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Comment: Since the value is dynamic hence the code snippet above has no control over it, I don't think this is best solution. The solution lies encoding the single quote to avoid it generating syntax error. Alternatively re-writing the code to avoid using <% syntax altogether. So will down vote.

Comment: Agreed.  This is basically suggesting that the OP update all backing data instead of dynamically escape the values in the output.  That seems like a non-starter.